# Chi-squared test for three-way contingency table (i.e., array) in R

Tags: chi-squared-test

In base R, the function `chisq.test()` "performs chi-squared contingency table tests and goodness-of-fit tests".

However, `chisq.test()` only takes a numeric `vector` or `matrix`, and not a three-way (three-dimensional) contingency table.

Is there a similar function for a three-way contingency table (i.e., `array`) in R?

Comment: I think you will find the information you need in the linked thread. Please 
read it. If it isn't what you want / you still have a question afterwards, 
come back here & edit your question to state what you learned & what you still 
need to know. Then we can provide the information you need without just 
duplicating material elsewhere that already didn't help you.

Comment: Thanks @gung, one question -is the second (not your accepted) answer to the question (that basically says "a three dimensional contingency table is actually pretty much analogue to the standard variant" on the wrong track?

Comment: I would not use that method, @Joshua. If you have a 3-d table, & you only want to know if rows are independent of columns, & don't care about pages, you could use the [Cochran Mantel Haenszel test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cochran%E2%80%93Mantel%E2%80%93Haenszel_statistics) (in `R`, [?mantelhaen.test](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/mantelhaen.test.html)).

Comment: This likely reflects a misunderstanding about Chi-square tests of proportion, but I'm interested in evaluating the standardized residuals to determine whether a specific cell is more or less likely than would be expected. I'm specifically interested in whether a cell for a specific row, column, and page is greater (or lesser) than expected.

Comment: I wonder if I'm missing your point, but that sounds fine. I would probably use a log linear model for that.

Comment: Using your example and `MASS::loglm()` I made my data into an `array` and used the model formula `row_name + column_name + page_name` (with the actual row, column, and page names), the evaluated the standardized residuals to determine whether a specific cell is more or less likely than expected. Given limited info., does this sound like reasonable way to go?

Comment: It's hard to say. Do you wonder about all 3 variables, or do you only care about r x c, w/ p as a nuisance variable?

Comment: In this case, I care about all 3 - each are substantively important and I am viewing them as independent of each other

Comment: That seems fine, then.

Comment: This has been working well for my analysis. However, I am unsure whether it is possible to calculate an effect size like Cramer's V for a chi-square test. Can you suggest how to calculate the effect size?

Comment: That's a viable new question. But you would need to specify what you want the effect size to measure.

Comment: I did my best to ask this here http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/252141/effect-size-for-correlation-of-variables